# MySQL - OS tied users

Tags: mysql, authentication

So, I'm trying to find this option and I can't find it in the docs. I need to know if there is a way in MySQL in which every user on the OS is also a User on the dB.

Just to clarify, when using Informix, each user on the OS itself is also capable of running dbacces and ,provided it has enough permissions, select insert and delete from a table. But you never "created" a user in Informix, it's simply part of the OS.

Does MySQL handle that?

Comment: Something does not happen because you invent stuff, so no, it wont happen. Which can be a good thing. From the security point of view, tying layer 7 users to system users is not the brightest of the ideas.

Comment: no, but you could write a script or use Ansible or something to manage local users and database accounts

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro exactly. I'm trying to implement it to prove q point. I personally think is an awful idea.

Comment: It is a concept from the 80s...Nothing prevents you of creating the same users, same password on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. Users in MySQL are stored in the `mysql.user` table. There is no connection whatsoever between MySQL users and OS users.

However, nothing prevents you from creating a shell script that manages the creation and deletion of users in parallel in the database and the OS.